# Where is PageControl contained in UIPageViewController referenced to?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I want to get height of UIPageControl presented in UIPageViewController dragged out from Object Library to my storyboard.

It is neither visible in the storyboard's UIPageViewController (so I can not Ctrl-drag to make an outlet), nor it is described in UIPageViewController class reference?

How can I get a reference to the UIPageControl object then?

Even on the Document Outline accessible in storyboard (which appears upon clicking little button on bottom left corner of the storyboard as @sasquatch pointed out) there is no UIPageControl object listed. This is what is presented:

[image]

Comment: Have you managed how to work with it? I'm just stuck with the same thing...

Comment: @Voyteck Did you get the reference?

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift 2.2 the following should work.

```
UIPageControl.appearance()
```

UIPageControl conforms to the UIAppearnce Protocol and had access to this method.

This is techinically the UIPageControls "appearance proxy" but should work for you.

You can read more about this here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearance